# Ignorar llaves que estén adentro del match inicial

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular

```
class\ \s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\ \s*extends\ \s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\s*\{[\s\S]*?\}
```

Esta expresión regular hace match por ejemplo a este texto

```
class ejemplo extends prueba {
    ...
}
```

El problema es que si el string tiene llaves adentro de las llaves de inicio y cierre principales, el match no es el esperado

**String**

```
class ejemplo extends prueba {
    ...
     {}
}
```

**Matches**

```
class ejemplo extends prueba {
    ...
     {}
```

**Resultado esperado**

```
class ejemplo extends prueba {
    ...
     {}
}
```

No tengo opción de usar `new Function("return ...")()` ya que el string se obtiene de un archivo y puede tener más cosas aparte del string mostrado, por eso si ejecuto una función podría ejecutarse todo antes de que se necesite, solo necesito obtener todas las clases que extiendan a otra

Comment: La evaluación del cuerpo de la clase no debería ser peresoza, sino codiciosa `\{[\s\S]*\}`. En caso que hubiera mas de una clase definida aplicaría la expresión completa.

Comment: Podría ser útil agregar un salto de línea antes de la llave de cierre: `class\ \s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\ \s*extends\ \s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\s*\{[\s\S]*?\n\}`, pero ese cierre debe estar en la primera columna.

Comment: ¿No te generará problemas cuando el extends se encuentre en otra línea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `^class` al inicio y `\}$` al final de tu expresión regular para garantizar que tome a la última llave:

```js
let re = /^\s*class\ \s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\ \s*extends\ \s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\s*\{[\s\S]*?\}$/g

let str = `class Temp extends Prueba { ... {} }`

console.log(re.exec(str));
```

Naturalmente eso no garantiza que la cantidad de paréntesis estén balanceados.

Comment: A tu expresión le hacía falta un `\s*` al inicio para que ignore espacios, espero no moleste si lo agrego; por otro lado ¡muchas gracias!